# Finding possible integer coordinates of a triangle

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> There are some triangles of positive area that have one vertex at (0,0) and the other two vertices are drawn independently with replacement from the set{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,.....,n} . How many triangles of such type are possible ?

It is easy to choose any four coordinates from the replacement set . However , the three pairs of coordinates cannot be the same and also they **must not be collinear**.
How can I generalize this for coordinates permissible till **n**?

Comment: Hint: Check slopes.

Comment: @Ravi Yeah , checking for slope would also get rid of duplicate coordinates .But how do I check the slope ?

Comment: $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are collinear with the origin iff $ad-bc=0$. So your problem is essentially equivalent to counting the $2\times 2$ *invertible* matrices with entries in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am unaware of matrix operations .

Comment: In such a case, disregard the *matrix* part. You have to count how many $(a,b,c,d)\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\}^4$ fulfill $ad=bc$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And this would account for duplicate coordinates as well,right ?

Comment: @user488460: of course, if $(a,b)=(c,d)$ then $ad=bc$.